# *Actually* getting nginx to reload config

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a subdomain with nginx on Ubuntu 13.04.  I was actually able to do this before with:

```
server {
    root /home/ajcrites/projects/site-a/public/;
    server_name sub.localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then `http://sub.localhost` would work perfectly.

Now, I've copied the same config and just changed `root` (to a path that exists) and `server_name` to some other value like `subber.localhost`.  No matter what I do, I can't get `subber.localhost` to work.  Also no matter what I do, I can't get `sub.localhost` to *not* work while nginx is running.  What's weird is that nginx actually will complain about errors in the config files, but even if there are none it doesn't matter.  *Only* `sub.localhost` will work.

I've tried doing all of the following, repeatedly and with various combinations:

- Create a separate file in `sites-available`.  nginx seems to thing that it's there since it will complain about errors when I try to reload.
- `service nginx stop && service nginx start`
- `nginx stop; nginx`
- `nginx -s reload`

When I `stop` it, `pgrep` does not show any `nginx` process, so it seems like it is correctly getting stopped.  This does not appear to be a cache issue as a fresh browser instance reacts the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to have had similar problems, each time that was a simple issue (that took me a long time to find though). For instance (sorry if some points are obvious - but sometimes we focus on the difficult, ignoring the obvious - at least that's my case)

- ensure the symlink is present in `sites-enabled`
- *root* path has read access all the way from `/` (at at least `x`) for the *nginx* user
- is `subber.localhost` well defined in `/etc/hosts` for local tests (or local DNS),

Maybe you could try to force the IP on which *listen* is listening. Eg instead of

```
listen 80
```

you could try

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80;     # OR
listen 192.168.0.1:80;   # you local address (or remote if that's the case)
```

Comment: Argh!  That darn `/etc/hosts` entry got me!  Do you have any idea why `sub.localhost` continues to work though even though it's gone from the config?

Comment: Browser cache maybe. At least Chrome maintains a cache ([this illustration for instance](http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)). Regarding *nginx*, if a virtual host is unavailable, it goes back to the default - maybe this is what you got?

Comment: @Explosion Pills, I would say that sub.localhost is getting serviced by the default host.  Most of the time, requests for a domain name not explicitly configured are handled that way.